# Can we connect Oracle apex to Control-M?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, control-m

Can we connect Oracle  Apex to Control-M in such a way that I can manage my jobs present in Control-M through Apex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the answer would be yes, since Control-M publishes some form of REST APIs

https://docs.bmc.com/docs/automation-api/918/control-m-automation-api-home-783053197.html

which APEX can handle no problems.

https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/creating-a-crud-form-on-a-rest-service-with-apex-181

Comment: Thanks for the info @Scott. I would need to look more deeply in that I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Oracle APEX can be integrated with Control-M using Control-M automation API

https://docs.bmc.com/docs/automation-api/9019monthly/control-m-automation-api-home-872868677.html